# Facebook is not fully loaded inside the electron window. And I get UncaughtErrors in the browser console. What might be the cause?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

mainWindow.loadURL('https://facebook.com')

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ta6g0.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off nodeIntegration  using nodeIntegration :false when using third party web urls in your window. Else Your computer will be at risk.

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: false
    }
  })
  mainWindow.loadURL('https://www.facebook.com/');
```